# How to reference a C# String in a seperate Javascript file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I currently have an issue where my JavaScript currently works when on my main section. However, when I Have put this into a seperate JavaScript file it no longer recognises the String I reference from the C# file as I reference it like `<% =Data %>` I was wondering how I would reference this in a separate JavaScript file.

Answer (score 0):

I think it 'is  not possible to reference a c# variables directly in a separate javascript file.
you must  declare a jacascript variable  to reference this variable in a html or aspx, ascx file then use the declaration in a javascript file.